# Is there a way to deploy a keyboard layout in win7?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I have around 50 machines that need a spanish layout installed, The only solutions i can find are related to modifying windows deployments or wim files. These systems are already setup and just need the new keyboard layout.

Comment: You should be able to push the changes like any application.  Configure a script file that will install the layout then reconfigure the system.

Comment: I don't even know what the script would begin to look like, do you have an example?

Comment: http://www.techieshelp.com/set-keyboard-layout-with-a-gpo/ found this with very little effort and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ec6a290e-fc09-4be6-9f6a-1f532d338606/change-regional-settings-locale-settings-and-keyboard-layout-using-group-policy?forum=winserverGP and http://superuser.com/questions/353752/windows-7-change-region-and-language-settings-using-a-script